# force download of msi file

Tags: php, html, http-headers, download

I must be having a dense day. I can't seem to figure this out.

I have a page on my website which should force the download of the msi file, but I want to leave the page's html shown with download instructions.

So far, I have tried the following tag in the html (note I only have access to the body of this page)

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=file.msi">
```

however in firefox this showed the binary file as garbled text.

Next I tried the following php inserted

```
$file = "file.msi";
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 5');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
exit;
```

However this closed the tab/window and not leaving the install instructions.

finally, I tried the following back in the html:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="application/octet-stream"> 
<meta http-equiv="content-disposition" content="attachment; filename=file.msi" />
```

But this refuses to download the file.
Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Apache, if you wanted to use a `.htaccess` file you could add the following:

```
AddType application/octet-stream .msi
```

As per [this source](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/htaccess/force-files-to-download-not-open-in-browser/). You could then just link to the file.

Answer (score 0):

`<meta>` tags apply to the page they're embedded in. They will not change how a file is downloaded, which is considered a completely separate page.

You should have something like `<a href="downloadmsi.php" target="_new" />download</a>` so that the download occurs in a different window than the instructions page.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this link](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/304496-trouble-with-forced-download-of-msi-file/) that helped me create a PHP file to link to that would specify the .msi to download. Worked the first time.

Visible Download Page, downloads.php, maybe

```
<a href="/downloads/?version=App.Installer.msi">download now</a>
```

Sever Processing Page from href above, i.e. example.com/downloads/index.php

```
$root = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
$file_dl = $_GET['version'];
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$file_dl);
header('Content-type: application/x-ole-storage');
readfile($root.'/downloads/'.$file_dl);
```

Also, not sure if it was necessary, but I added to the .htaccess file: `AddType application/octet-stream .msi` as suggested by [Marc B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118068/marc-b)